# Python Multiprocessing stops inexplicably to process function inside for loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

During a parallel multiprocessing process on Python 3.10, python stops to process function inside for loop. At the beginning, everything works well and at a certain time, the function2 inside the for loop is not processed anymore.
No error is reported. I have checked that the function 1 is still feed with new data, but the function 1 results is not sent to function2.
I don't understand what happens. Do you have any idea ?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import logging
import signal
import sys, os
from rich.progress import Progress

def initializer():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

def CPU_Parallelization(Nb_CoresToBeUsed,
                        output_queue,
                        input_data,
                        output_result):
mp.util.log_to_stderr(mp.util.DEBUG)

p = mp.Pool(processes=Nb_CoresToBeUsed, initializer=initializer)

        with Progress() as progress:
        try:
            # Bar Progress Increment
            task_id = progress.add_task("[cyan]Working...", total=len(input_data))

            with p as pool:
                for Out_1,\
                    Out_2,\
                    Out_3,\
                    Out_4 in pool.imap(function1, input_data):

                    final_output = function2(out_1, Out2, Out3, Out4)
                    progress.advance(task_id)


            p.close()
            p.join()

         except Exception as e: # <---
            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
            fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
            print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
            print(e)
            p.close()
            p.join()


def funct1(input_data):
    try:
        Out1 = 1
        Out2 = 2
        Out3 = 3
        Out4 = 4
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return Out1, Out2, Out3, Out4
```

Comment: You've made a number of typos in trying to extract this example, so it's hard to tell.  How can you tell `function2` doesn't run?  In your example, you don't put the data anywhere.

Comment: I can tell that function2 doesn't run as this function is saving images into the disk and also save data into csv file. From a certain moment, function2 is no more called as no more images are saved and csv file is no more updated. In addition, I also tried to print current time just before function 2 to evaluate the last time of the function2 call.

Comment: And you're quite sure you haven't simply hit the end of the dataset?

Comment: Absolutely. I am absolutely sure.